# Intuitively, attributes and properties are similar/the same; what, if anything, differentiates them?

Tags: terminology, semantics, properties, objects

We use words like *attributed to* and *property of*, and *attribute of*, but is there any difference of meaning? Both seem to imply characteristics or qualities of objects but that doesn't feel very foundational judging by how important both properties and attributes are.

Comment: A helpful place to start at a diagonal to both terms is talk of *predicates.* These are alongside quantifiers and propositional operators, which directly and indirectly apply to variables and their attached predicates. Predicates tend to get assimilated to properties; quantifiers are notoriously non-properties in this context. So maybe we'd talk of attributing a quantifier to a variable, but not talk of the quantifier's function being a property of the applied-to variable. OTOH in the base language we can talk of attributing a property to something, so I'm unsure how strict the distinction is.

Comment: Yes, they are the same.

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately, that will depend upon how any given author is stipulating intended meanings.

I would say that one may assume synonymy relative to the discussion over description theory in which Russellian description is "attributive," Strawsonian/Fregean description is "referential," and Neale's analysis of facts speaks of a class of "demonstrative" descriptions.

The "attributive" interpretation relates to the debate over whether or not one can "define" an existent. The received view with respect to why Leibniz' principle of the identity of indiscernibles is not considered to be a "logical" principle in first-order logic follows from the preference to reject the defining of existents.

In the first-order paradigm, descriptions are deprecated via Russell's attributive interpretation and addressed in the model theory through Beth's definability theorem.

Through the opinions which characterized these historical debates "properties" and "attributes" are linked in a manner justifying synonymy.

Still, individual writers are sometimes trying to expose subtle distinctions that require using apparent synonyms differently. When a distinction "makes a stand" (Aristotle), Gricean agreements based upon what is "intuitive" may fail.

Answer (score 0):

Attribute and property in ordinary language are synonyms. However, what differentiates them is how a philosopher uses them.

For example, Spinoza defined attribute as just the essence of a substance under some way of concieving or describing the substance.

Whereas for a natural philosopher, that is a physicist, an attribute is a measured property of something. Here attribute is synonymous with property and both are different to what Spinoza regarded as an attribute.